# Redis server connection error in laravel v4.2

Tags: php, laravel, redis

Hi I working in laravel v4.2. Now I want to send push notifications to users in queue so for this purpose I use redis server for queue push notifications. But the problem is that I want use the redis server of of other server instead of home/local server. Is there any solution to solve this problem. Below is my queue.php file configuration that I am using

```
'redis' => array(
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'cluster' => true,
            'default' => array(
                'host' => '192.168.1.244',
                'port' => 6379,
                'database' => 0,
                'password' => ''
            ),
```

If I use my own pc IP address then I receice queue notification but when I try to use the other pc redis server then I receive following error in exception

```
Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]
```

Please let me know if anyone know that how to cofigure or user redis server remotely.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue issue in my code I was doing configuration in queue.php instead of database.php file. So when I change the host in database.php file then I become able to work with redis server.